# Segmentation Fault on second time calling mysql_fetch_row

Tags: c++, mysql, segmentation-fault

I am writing some MYSQL embedded into C++ and I am getting some behavior that I haven't been able to pinpoint the cause of.

I have a main function and two functions that can search by author or publisher.  If I search by author, I get the proper results the first time. If I search by publisher, I don't ever get any results the first time.  However, no matter what I do, the second time I call one of the functions I get a segmentation fault at the line "mysql_fetch_row" in the while loops.  I'm assuming I am leaving some kind of connection open that is conflicting with the second call but I have not been able to figure it out.

Sorry for the wall of code but I'm not sure where in the program the issue is coming from. I tried to describe each part and noted where the program crashes in each of the two functions.

Main function, connects to the database and calls the other two functions

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void searchByAuthor(MYSQL *connect);
void searchByPublisher(MYSQL *connect);

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;

    MYSQL *connect, mysql;
    connect = mysql_init(&mysql);

    //connect to the database
    connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASENAME, 0,
        NULL, 0);

 //Get user input here to select what to search by
 //Loops until user quits the program

    return 0;

}
```

Search By Author - Gets the user input and makes the SQL call.  Returns results correctly the first time.

```
void searchByAuthor(MYSQL *connect)
{
    string name;
    string sql = "select Title, Price, Type, AuthorFirst, AuthorLast from Book, Author, Wrote where Author.AuthorNum=Wrote.AuthorNum and Wrote.BookCode = Book.BookCode and AuthorLast=\'" + name + "\'";

    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    cout << "Enter the last name of the author" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    mysql_query(connect, (sql).c_str());

    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

//Crashes here on second call
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
    {
        cout << endl << row[0] << " "
            << row[1] << " " << row[2] << " "
            << row[3] << " " << row[4] << endl;

    }

    mysql_free_result(res_set);
    mysql_close(connect);
}
```

Search By Publisher - Gets user input and makes the SQL call - Does not ever return any results.

```
void searchByPublisher(MYSQL *connect)
{
    string publisher;
    string sql = "select Book.Title from Book, Publisher where Publisher.PublisherName =\'" + publisher + "\' and Publisher.PublisherCode = Book.PublisherCode";

    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row = NULL;

    cout << "Enter the name of the publisher" << endl;
    cin >> publisher;

    mysql_query(connect, sql.c_str());

    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

//Crashes here on second call
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL) 
    {

        cout << endl << row[0] << endl;
    }

    mysql_free_result(res_set);
    mysql_close(connect);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it skip right past the while loop then?  Or is that not what you are referring to?

Comment: I have checked and it returns a few valid values. None of which are null.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Even if that's happening, why would it cause a segfault when calling `mysql_fetch_row`? The segfault should happen when trying to print `row[0]` if it's null.

Comment: Yes, it is mysql_fetch_row that is causing the crash. I put a cout between the fetch and the output, and the cout doesn't get called.

Comment: You *did* run in a debugger to pinpoint the crash location, did you not? Then you would know exactly on what line in your code the crash happens, if it's in the `mysql_fetch_row` function call, or when you do `std::cout << ...`.

Comment: Okay, then disregard my previous comments. You should still check for `NULL` values anyway.

Comment: Then tell me this: Is the crash happening on the second call to e.g. `searchByPublisher`, or in the second call to `mysql_fetch_row` in the loop?

Comment: The solution is below. It was because I was closing the connection and then trying to access the database again.

Comment: That API design lol ``void mysql_query(connection, queryString)`` lol - sure works great in multithreaded environments....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the connection using `mysql_close(connect)` but not sure if you reopen the connection before querying again? Check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-close.html) when you close it the handle is also closed.

Also check your mysql database if you have any null values in it.

Comment: That was it! Sometime's things like that can be staring at you right in the face and you still miss it.  I am still not getting any result back when searching by publisher.  However, I get results when I manually query the database with the same statement, and I get results when I use "select * from Book" in my function.  I read somewhere that it might have to do with the single quotes in the statement, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in `mysql_init()`. the parameter of `mysql_init` must be NULL not `&mysql`.

It must be so:

```
connect = mysql_init(NULL);
```